# How to update ExtendScript UI DropDownList Dynamically?

Tags: drop-down-menu, extendscript

I just want my dropdownlist updated when I click on it, My code already works but I cant select them. my code are bellow:

```
myPanel.grp.groupDriver.myPanel.myDropDownList.onActivate = function(){
  alert("Hi");
     var myDD = myPanel.grp.groupDriver.myPanel.myDropDownList;
     while (myDD.items.length) myDD.remove(myDD.items[0]);
     for(var i=1; i <= comp.numLayers; i++){
       myPanel.grp.groupDriver.myPanel.myDropDownList.add('Item', 
comp.layer(i).name);
     };
}
```

Comment: I'm here because I'm also trying to do this with InDesign. My issue is that `onActivate` simply doesn't trigger when the drop down list is clicked on. What do you mean when you say, 'my code already works but I cant select them'? Did you find a solution?

Comment: BTW, you don't need a while loop just to empty the drop down list. There's a `removeAll()` method for that.